# Relative URL to Absolute URL

Tags: url

Base URL : "http://example.com/foo/bar"
Relative URL : /hoge/fuga

Then is Absolute URL is "http://example.com/hoge/fuga" or 
"http://example.com/foo/bar/hoge/fuga" ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: `/hoge/fuga` is server-root-relative, so absolute will be `http://example.com/hoge/fuga`. However, it'll take about less than 60 sec. to try it yourself. Less than writing this question.

Comment: actually i was reading a book and it saids the answer is http://example.com/foo/bar/hoge/fuga

Comment: I just want to be sure if it is right or not so..

Comment: http://example.com/foo/bar/hoge/fuga"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are asking how to calculate from relative url to absolute url.

When you start with "/", it starts from your Base URL.

```
Base URL : "http://example.com/foo/bar" 
Relative URL : /hoge/fuga
Absolute URL: "http://example.com/hoge/fuga"
```

If you want it to calculate from your start place use without starting "/"

```
Base URL : "http://example.com/foo/bar" 
Relative URL : hoge/fuga
Absolute URL: "http://example.com/foo/bar/hoge/fuga"
```

Comment: Your second example is wrong. `http://example.com/foo/bar` + `hoge/fuga` = `http://example.com/foo/hoge/fuga`. Relative paths are relative to the current directory. Since the starting URL doesn't end in a slash, that means the current dir is `/foo/`.